# Question regarding Monolithic vs. Microservice Architecture

Tags: docker, kubernetes, architecture

I'm currently rethinking an architecture I was planning.
So suppose I have a system where there are about 8 different services interacting with a single database. Some services listen and react to database events and do stuff like sending SMS.
Then there's an API layer sitting on top of the database and a frontend connected to this API. So in my understanding this is rather monolithic.

In fact I don't see any advantage of using containers in this scenario. Their real advantage is that they can be swapped out, right? My intuition tells me that there is often no purpose in doing that except maybe some load balancing on API level. Instead many companies just seem to blindly jump on the hype train of containerizing everything.

Now the question arises, is docker the right tool for this context? In each forum people refrain from using docker for the sole purpose of a more resource efficient "VM" aggregating all services within a single container. However this is the only real scenario I'd see any advantages in using docker (the environment, e.g. alpine-linux, is the same on all customer's computers when rolling out the system).

Even docker-compose is not "grouping" containers together as a complete system only exposing port 443 but instead starts an infrastructure of multiple interacting containers. Oftentimes services like Kubernetes are then used for deploying these infrastructures on "nodes", i.e. VMs.

However, in my opinion it would be great to have a single self-contained container without putting them into a VM. This container would include every necessary service only exposing one port, e.g. 443.

Since I'm rather confused now, I'd really appreciate your help here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes does many things and has many useful features. But Kubernetes also require that you architect your apps to follow [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) principles. An important thing here is that your apps are *stateless*.

- When the app is stateless, it is easy to **scale out horizontally** - this can also be done automatically when the load increases.
- When the app is stateless, it is easy to do *Rolling Deployments* that upgrade the app to a new version without downtime.
- You can run containers on bare metal Linux servers, but this is mostly very big servers. If you use a cloud, you probably want more VM instances, but distributed to 3 Availability Zones - for increased availability.
- "Self-contained container - exposing one port". With Kubernetes, you typically use a *private network* and you only expose services via a single *load balancer* - typically on a port, but different URLs send traffic to different services.

> Some services listen and react to database events and do stuff like sending SMS.

As I said, many things is easier when it is horizontal scalable, but this kind of app - that listen for events and react - is one of few examples where you **can not** scale horizontally. But it is a good fit for a serverless architecture instead, possibly on Kubernetes using [Knative](https://knative.dev/).

> Now the question arises, is docker the right tool for this context?

My opinion is that most workload will run in containers. It is more a question about how it should be run in Kubernetes - one or multiple replicas. As stateless [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) or stateful [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) or some other way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll research further into this direction!